# & symbol not accepting in jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net

Why & symbol not accepting in jquery ajax?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

Use `&amp;` instead: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/8851.htm